# I cant get iframes to work

Tags: iframe

I realize this is probably a stupid question but I cant get iframes to work, I'm assuming the src is the only attribute required, I have checked some examples but I still dont understand the issue.

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your code is not wrong. Face book is blocking itself from being loaded into iframes.  There are security considerations when working with cross domain sites

Comment: ok that makes sense thanks